# How to implement a real time tracking mechanism in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to implement a 'first seen' and 'last seen' way of tracking messages coming in from a RFID reader.

The following code manage to track each unique message and update it every 5mins.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import datetime as dt

time_interval = dt.timedelta(minutes=5)

dic1 = {}
update = []   

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
    epc =  line[1]
    rfid_input = "EPC_NO.: " + epc[11:35]
    when = dt.datetime.strptime(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


    if rfid_input not in dic1 or (when - dic1[rfid_input] > time_interval):
        dic1[rfid_input] = when
        update.append(dic1)
        for key, value in update[-1].items():
            print (key, value)
        print ()
```

How can I keep track of the 'first-seen' date & time and print it out?

Something like:

```
# At the very beginning
EPC_NO.: 012345  FIRST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 08:59:33    LAST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 08:59:33
EPC_NO.: 056789  FIRST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:00:23    LAST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:00:23

# 5 mins later
EPC_NO.: 012345  FIRST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 08:59:33    LAST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:04:33
EPC_NO.: 056789  FIRST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:00:23    LAST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:05:23

# 10 mins later **(EPC_NO.: 056789 is not read)
EPC_NO.: 012345  FIRST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 08:59:33    LAST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:09:33
EPC_NO.: 056789  FIRST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:00:23    LAST SEEN AT 2016-04-18 09:05:23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a class to gather all information you need :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import datetime as dt

time_interval = dt.timedelta(minutes=5)

dic1 = {}


class EPC():
    def __init__(self,when):
        self.first_seen = when
        self.last_print = when
        self.last_seen = when

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    payloadjson = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    line = payloadjson["value"].split(',')
    epc =  line[1]
    rfid_input = "EPC_NO.: " + epc[11:35]
    when = dt.datetime.today()

    if rfid_input not in dic1:
        dic1[rfid_input] = EPC(when)
        print_all = True

    else:
        dic1[rfid_input].last_seen = when
        print_all = when-dic1[rfid_input].last_print > time_interval

    if print_all:
        for (key, value) in dic1.items():
            first_str = "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d"%(value.first_seen.year,value.first_seen.month,value.first_seen.day,value.first_seen.hour,value.first_seen.minute,value.first_seen.second)
            last_str = "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d"%(value.last_seen.year,value.last_seen.month,value.last_seen.day,value.last_seen.hour,value.last_seen.minute,value.last_seen.second)

            print "EPC_NO.: %06d    FIRST SEEN AT %s    LAST SEEN AT %s"%(key, first_str,last_str)
            value.last_print = when
```

I am not able to test it so tell me if there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Vince! I just tried your solution and I'm seeing  `print_all = when - testlist[rfid_input].last_print > time_interval
 // TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`. Is there a better way to handle data types?

Comment: I think is better to maintain the `when` as a `datetime.datetime` object. Provide more flexibility tho.

Comment: Yes you are totally right about it. It should be better now.